# log out any user from admin screen when admin click log out button

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

[image]
Hi Guys...
I have made each user based authorization on my website, every user has different rights. 
From the admin screen, I can assign new rights to the user. That assigned user logs out from that browser and I store their login info in that session. Then I assign the user their rights, and the assigned user is log in right can't apply 
so I need to the user log out from master screen
Is it possible?
if it is possible please give flow
thank you

Comment: On clicking Log out you can store a bit in your UserTable say "ForceLogOut" - on your website you can ping your server in every 30 seconds - and if this bit is true then you can logout the user.

Comment: Thank you, Ranjit Singh, but any other way you have please told me

Comment: that functionality using in the very rare case may be in month one time, so can't give load on every 30 second and session value can't change in every 30 second

Comment: Just have the server expire their session. They'll have to re-authenticate on next web interaction.

Comment: You can give a try for websockets. That helps you to inform your clients to logout and your users will login back

Comment: *if it is possible please give flow* That's too broad. And opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks McMurphy how to clear user server session i  think i need to R&D on that

Comment: Thank You Gert Arnold.. you are right.. !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use websockets/[SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/) to do such kind of task.

On a high level, you will have a hubs where you will be able to send needed info to your clients. 
Whenever a new user logins, you can add that user to be notified and if at all your admin tries to change settings of a user, Hubs can be used to send a message to that user.

Comment: thanks but that is not solution that i want SignalR is used  for notification  to send but this method only admin can use and no send any information to user click and log out selected user

Comment: Yes agreed that it is notification system. But has an option to notify your client (your client browser) to do a logout when your admin does some action.

Comment: Ohh thank you, i am not known about that let i do some r & d on that

Comment: Sure. I am pretty sure you will love SignalR feature for this.